# add sound at the end of a wave file in matlab

Tags: matlab, audio

I have a big wave file that I want to add some sounds at the end of it. and because i do this adding in a loop it is not wise to read it every time and add a short part and close it(in this way the algorithm is so SLOW).
is there any more optimized way to just add a sound file at the end of another in matlab(wave file)?

Answer (score 1):

How about keeping it in memory while appending?

```
big   = wavread('big.wav');
flist = dir('*.wav');
for i=1:length(flist)
  short = wavread(flist(i).name);
  big = [big, short];
end
wavwrite(big, 'bigger.wav');
```

If you know how many samples you want to add to `big` vector it's faster if you preallocate the space needed.

Comment: I use this procedure but it is also slow I want NOT to read the BIG file,it is really big!!

Comment: `wavwrite` doesn't support appending, so you're left with using `fread`/`fwrite` but that might become complicated when dealing with the wav header, so perhaps deal with the data in a header-less state. How about using an external program? [`sox`](http://sox.sf.net) can easily do this efficiently, to concatenate two files: `sox long.wav short.wav -t wavpcm longer.wav`.